# Mysql How to delete a records by setting the values and counts

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struck in mysql query that i want to delete a rows by setting the values and count.
For example
if i have ids 1,2,3,1,1,1 rows
and my values are 1, 2 to pass into the arguments.i.e

`Delete From TableName where id(1,2)`.

I need only 'row one' and 'row 2' to be delete then my records should show 3,1,1,1.
if i again delete i.e

`Delete From TableName where id(3,1,1)`,

then the table should contains only one row 1.
Thanking you.

Comment: what do you mean for 'row one' and 'row 2'  in sql you can work on column content  .. there is  not an implicit order ..

Comment: the sequence i explain look like records i.e rows 1,2,3,1,1,1 so totally 6 rows

Comment: the sequence don't explain  .. nothing (there is not an implicit order by in SQL).. if you delete id 1 you delete all the rows with id 1  not the first  ... there is not a first id 1  .. if you need  this you must use others columns for define what you are calling the "first "

Comment: I think you need to show us the table definition so we can better understand the problem

Comment: you cannot. Although, you can delete only one row by: delete from tableName where id=1 limit 1. This will remove only one row.